# IE 7 and 8 not adding class

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, addclass

In this example I basically only want to make an element transulcent if they've got JavaScript enabled. I'm doing this by adding the class called 'trancent' within a .js file. However when checking backwards compatibility IE 7 and 8 for some reason even though their adding the class, the styling isn't working. Their also successfully  removing a different class within the same file. It's not an issue in any other browser or even later IEs.

Can anyone decipher why IE 7 and 8 are doing this?

```
(function(){
$('.contentdivbody .lightblue').removeClass('invis');
$('.nonejavainfo').slideUp(0);

logolist = $('.logolist li img');
masssarea = $('#maparea .mapele');

logolist.addClass('trancent');
masssarea.addClass('trancent');
$('#maparea .mapelerings').addClass('invis');

$("a.newwindow").click(function() {
         window.open(this.href);
         return false;
});
})();
```

*css*

`.trancent{
    opacity: 0.7;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 and IE8 do not support the `opacity` style, so my guess is that the jQuery is adding the class just fine, but it's not doing anything because as far as IE is concerned there's no styles there.

If you need to support opacity in old IE versions, add the following styles to your class:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)"; /* IE8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* IE6, IE7 */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I figured out it was adding the class just before posting the question but forgot to re-type the question.

Comment: And yes, that was exactly the problem,

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I'm gonna have to remember hitting enter posts the comment :-/. EDIT And I just realized there's a edit button :-/ :-/

Comment: @Noodlemanny - no worries. glad it was helpful. Hit the 'tick' icon by the answer to mark it as accepted.